# SQL- Need to conditionally sum a column

Tags: sql

```
|  PlayID |  Passing_Yards |  Receptions |  Position |  Player_Name  | Rec_Yds
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1234   |  0             |  1          |  WR       |  Bill Schmill | ???
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1234   |  20            |  0          |  QB       |  Joe Schmoe   | ???
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using an NFL SQL database to try and calculate how many receiving yards a player has based on a specific "play ID" number. There is no column for "receiving yards", so I need to derive that based on the "passing yards" in the same play (using the play ID). How can I create a new column for "receiving yards" that will be calculated based on the "play ID" and the "passing yards" for that play? Basically, the receptions will need to equal 1 for that play, and I assume you'd need to sum based on the play ID?

Something like:

```
SELECT PlayID, Passing_Yards, Receptions, Position, Player_Name, Sum(Passing_Yards)
FROM nfldb
GROUP BY PlayID, Passing_Yards, Receptions, Position, Player_Name
```

but that doesn't give me what I need.

Comment: If passing yards is in 1 table and receiver records in another, a JOIN on PlayId should get you what you need.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: postgreSQL...and thanks for cleaning my post up.

Comment: and no @Jon Raynor, the receiving records are not in another table. the stat I'm actually looking for is "receiving air yards", which only exists in the "passing" category. I'm just calling it receiving yards for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think window function will do what you want:

```
select n.*,
       (case when reception = 1
             then max(passing_yards) over (partition by playid)
             else 0
        end) as receiving_yards
from nfldb n;
```

The use of `max()` with `over` is ANSI standard syntax, which most databases support.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. I didn't mention that there are actually three columns that need to all be the same: play_id, drive_id, and game_id. I simply used

Comment: oops... I used (partition by play_id, game_id, drive_id). That seems to work, but is that how partition by is intended to be used?

Comment: @BYates . . . Your question doesn't mention those additional columns.  They would be appropriate if they are part of the definition of a 'specific "play ID" number'.